# React forwordRef with state

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap Collapse, and it manages the state of the collapsable item using useState hook like this:

```
function Example() {
 const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

 return (
   <>
    <Button onClick={() => setOpen(!open)} aria-controls="example-collapse-text" aria-expanded{open}>
    click
  </Button>
  <Collapse in={open}>
    <div id="example-collapse-text">
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus
      terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer
      labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
    </div>
  </Collapse>
  </>
);
}
```

Since I'm using this Collapsable item almost everywhere in my website I decided to create ref item and each time pass the collapsable data like this:

```
const CollapsableWidget = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
 <div className={classes.collapseWrapper}>
<div className={classes.collapseTitle} aria-controls={props.id} aria-expanded={props.open}>
  {props.title}
</div>
<Collapse in={props.open}>
  <div id={props.id} ref={ref}>
    {props.children}
  </div>
</Collapse>
 </div>
));
```

But I'm losing the option to "control" the open and setOpen for the collapsable item.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have to control its `open` state outside of the widget, you can have the state internal instead

```
const CollapsableWidget = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  ...
```

[image: Edit mutable-bash-o4erw]

If you do, then you can track your collapse states in, for example, an array

```
const [collapseStates, setCollapseStates] = useState([
  {
    id: "1",
    open: false,
    title: "click me",
    content: "content"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    open: false,
    title: "click me 2",
    content: "content 2"
  }
]);
```

[image: Edit busy-christian-xosfz]

Answer (score 0):

I think your ref props in the wrong place. it should be in component that you want to control.

Here it is:

```
const CollapsableWidget = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
     <div className={classes.collapseWrapper}>
    <div className={classes.collapseTitle} aria-controls={props.id} aria-expanded={props.open}>
      {props.title}
    </div>
    <Collapse in={props.open} ref={ref}>
      <div id={props.id}>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </Collapse>
     </div>
    ));
```

this is the changes

```
 <Collapse in={props.open} ref={ref}>
          <div id={props.id}>
            {props.children}
          </div>
        </Collapse>
```